# Is there any reason to keep a settings file nested underneath properties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

When I add a settings file in Visual Studio, by default, it ends up under properties (the first highlighted item below). Is there any reason it's inadvisable to move it out from under properties as I did with "SomeOtherSettings.settings" (second highlighted item)? This second settings file seems to work, and it populates everything as expected in "App.config".

[image: Settings]

I know I have two settings files in this project, but that's unrelated to the question I'm asking. I simply want to know if it's acceptable to move the settings file around in the project. The (tiny) benefit I see in doing this is that if I moved the original settings file out from under properties in the project structure, I could type:

```
string someStringFromSettings = Settings.Default.Setting1;
```

and get rid of "Properties" as is required otherwise:

```
string someStringFromSettings = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;
```

Comment: Generally, and by convention, folder name and namespaces are congruent...and the Properties namespace is where a lot of yer fellow devs are gonna expect to find settings.

Comment: Thanks! That's mostly what I expected, which is fine. Are there any other reasons you know of besides that specific convention? Do you think it's okay to take it out for projects that are small enough that the entire structure in Solution Explorer is always visible (such as the sample project above)? Typing "Properties." over and over (or rather selecting it from the Intellisense menu) is a very minor nuisance, but it also elongates individual lines of code (especially where a setting might be a parameter), and it clutters my code when I have to use a lot of settings in the same general area.

Comment: And yes, I know this isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: You can add `using Properties;` to the top of the file, too :-)  But you're right that you don't need to have the settings or properties folder at all.

Comment: Post as an answer, and I'll accept.